# Custom Event handler is getting called twice?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I've created an event handler that simply returns a list of objects that I receive from a web service when the call completes.

Now I went ahead and ran the app in debug mode and found out that the first time the event is called it works perfectly, but immediately after it completes the event is being fired for a second time. I've checked and am absolutely sure I am not calling the event more than once in the receiver class.

This is my first shot at creating custom event handlers inside my applications so I am not entirely sure the implementation is 100% accurate.

Any ideas of what might be causing this? Is the way I created the event handler accurate?

**This is the DataHelper class**

```
public class DataHelper
{
    public delegate void DataCalledEventHandler(object sender, List<DataItem> dateItemList);
    public event DataCalledEventHandler DataCalled;

    public DataHelper()
    {

    }

    public void CallData()
    {
        List<DataItem> dataItems = new List<DataItem>();
        //SOME CODE THAT RETURNS DATA
        DataCalled(this, dataItems);
    }
}
```

**This is where I subscribed to my event:**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   GetNewDataItems();
}
private void GetNewDataItems()
        {

                try
                {
                    DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper();
                    dataHelper.CallData();
                    dataHelper.DataCalled += new DataHelper.DataCalledEventHandler(dataHelper_DataCalled);

                }
                catch
                {
                   //Handle any errors
                }
            }
    }

    void dataHelper_DataCalled(object sender, List<DataItem> dataItemsList)
    {
        //Do something with results
        //NOTE: THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS WHEN EVENT IS FIRED FOR SECOND TIME
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you are subscribing to the event?

Comment: @WouterdeKort Sure thing, give me a second.

Comment: Why do you subscribe to the event `DataCalled` after the call to `CallData`? This way `CallData` will throw an exception because there are no subscribers to the `DataCalled` event if you have not subscribed elsewhere.

Comment: The code snippet is very strange, hard to imagine why you'd subscribe the event *after* calling the method.  It should *never* fire.  Post actual code, don't edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably you added the delegate twice, is it possible?

In this case the problem is not in who calls the delegate but in who adds the delegate to the event.

Probably you did something like...

```
private Class1 instance1;

void callback(...)
{
}

void myfunction()
{
    this.instance1.DataCalled += this.callback;
    this.instance1.DataCalled += this.callback;
}
```

If not, try to add a breakpoint where you subscribe to the event and see if it is called twice.

As a side note, you should always check for null when calling an event, if there is no subscriber you can get a NullReferenceException.
I would also suggest you to use a variable to store the event delegate to avoid the risk of multithreading failure.

```
public void CallData()
{
    List<DataItem> dataItems = new List<DataItem>();
    var handler = this.DataCalled;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, dataItems);
}
```

Edit: since now I see the code, is obvious that each time you call the GetNewDataItems method you are subsribing every time to the event.
Do in such a way you subscribe only once, for example, in constructor, or store your variable somewhere or deregister the event when you finish.

This code contains also a probable memory leak: every time you add a delegate you keep alive both the instance that contains the event and the instance that contains the subscribed method, at least, until both are unreferenced.

You can try to do something like this...

```
void dataHelper_DataCalled(object sender, List<DataItem> dataItemsList)
{
    // Deregister the event...
    (sender as Class1).DataCalled -= dataHelper_DataCalled; 

    //Do something with results
}
```

In this way however you must ensure that if there is not an exception during the event registration the event will be fired or you have again memory leaks.

Instead of an event perhaps you need just a delegate. Of course you should set your delegate field to null when you want to release the delegate.

```
// in data helper class

private DataHelper.DataCalledEventHandler myFunctor;

public void CallData(DataHelper.DataCalledEventHandler functor)
{
    this.myFunctor = functor;
    //SOME CODE THAT RETURNS DATA
}

// when the call completes, asynchronously...
private void WhenTheCallCompletes()
{
    var functor = this.myFunctor;
    if (functor != null)
    {
        this.myFunctor = null;
        List<DataItem> dataItems = new List<DataItem>();
        functor(this, dataItems);
    }
}
    
// in your function
...    dataHelper.CallData(this.dataHelper_DataCalled);    ...
```

Comment: No unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case. I originally thought It had to be added twice. I added some more code on top if you want to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent feedback. I was able to implement everything you mentioned. As for the problem, I figured it out. First I had to get past the "Null-Reference Exception" error by using your example. Then I realized I was making calls using HttpWebRequest in my DataHelper class. In that case you have to use BeginInvoke to marshal data to the UI thread. Strangely enough when the "Invalid cross-thread access" exception was thrown it was happening inside of the method that raised the event after the operation was complete.

Answer (score 2):

The below lines on your code should be flipped. That is

These lines

```
dataHelper.CallData();
dataHelper.DataCalled += new DataHelper.DataCalledEventHandler(dataHelper_DataCalled);
```

Should be:

```
dataHelper.DataCalled += new DataHelper.DataCalledEventHandler(dataHelper_DataCalled);
dataHelper.CallData();
```

Because you first need to attach the event handler and then call other methods on the object which can raise the event

Comment: Yes, True! Didn't notice it :) For this reason passing it as parameter in function seems a more natural choice.

Comment: @Ankur Yes it's a bad habit. I never really stopped doing it because it never threw an exception for me. But it definetly doesn't sound right to do it backwards. I will type it this way in the future. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well is not only a bad habit, since it is a code that is executed on another thread, it can complete BEFORE you subscribe to the event, so your callback can skip being executed sometime, randomly. This is dangerous and unpredictable.